# How can I refactor my code to clear off - "local variable 'data' referenced before assignment"

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-admin

My code returns is intended to return queryset based on selected dates or months however these two are almost similar yet only one works.

Here is my both forms.py

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
class MonthInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'month'
    
class DateRangeInputForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    end = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())

class MonthRangeInputForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateField(widget=MonthInput())
    end = forms.DateField(widget=MonthInput())
```

This is the query view that works.

```
def milk_records_range_per_day(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.DateRangeInputForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = (models.Milk.objects.filter(milking_date__date__range=(
                    form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']))
                    .annotate(date=functions.TruncDate("milking_date"))
                    .values("date")
                    .annotate(amt=Sum('amount_in_kgs')))
            labels = [c['date'].strftime("%d-%m-%Y") for c in data]
            values = [x['amt'] for x in data]
            .......
```

Though this one throws a reference error : local variable 'data' referenced before assignment

```
def milk_records_range_per_month(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.MonthRangeInputForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = (models.Milk.objects.filter(milking_date__month__range=(
                        form.cleaned_data['start'],form.cleaned_data['end']))
                        .annotate(month=functions.TruncMonth("milking_date"))
                        .values("month")
                        .annotate(amt=Sum('amount_in_kgs')))
            labels = [c['month'].strftime("%m-%Y") for c in data]
            values = [x['amt'] for x in data]
            .....
```

Model:

```
class Milk(models.Model):
    amount_in_kgs = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(50)])
    milking_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   ...
```

Comment: @willem-van-onsem Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your form is invalid.

Nesting the variables that use `data` variable would help:

```py
def milk_records_range_per_month(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.MonthRangeInputForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = (models.Milk.objects.filter(milking_date__month__range=(
                        form.cleaned_data['start'],form.cleaned_data['end']))
                        .annotate(month=functions.TruncMonth("milking_date"))
                        .values("month")
                        .annotate(amt=Sum('amount_in_kgs')))

                # Now the following two declarations are in this code block
                # where "data" variable is declared already.
                labels = [c['month'].strftime("%m-%Y") for c in data]
                values = [x['amt'] for x in data]
            .....
```

You could also set a default for `data` variable before the `if` code block:

```py
data = []
if form.is_valid():
...
```

The solution depends on your use-case.

PS. the issue is the same in both views (`milk_records_range_per_month` and `milk_records_range_per_day`).

Comment: Hello, when nested, the dictionaries ie. labels and values become unavailable and throws another reference error. I use the two dictionaries which is outside the scope of the if block yet just still within the function.
```
        context = dict(self.each_context(request),title="Milk records.",
                       form=form,labels=labels,values=values)
        return TemplateResponse(request, "milk_record_per_range_month.html", context)
```

Comment: Does solution 2 - setting a default work?

Comment: Solution 2 invalidates the form entries, it throws form error : Enter a valid date.

Comment: This means your form is invalid. You need to check which data are being passed to the form and why doesn't the form pass validation. You can't expect the form to always be valid. In fact, the form is invalid in the code in the post too, but the code fails before it can reach the part where it can return to you the error message.